# Input parameter without the "name" property in custom Integromat app

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I am trying to create a dropdown parameter (of type 'select') and it should contain two groups of nested parameters. But, I do not need to pass this top-level parameter to the API. I've tried removing the "name" property of this parameter, but then it doesn't remember the user's choice when the module is opened again. How can I include only the nested field in the request, but not the parent?

```json
[
  {
    "type": "select",
    "label": "Select",
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "A",
        "value": "a",
        "nested": [
          {
            "name": "a",
            "type": "text",
            "label": "a nested"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "B",
        "value": "b",
        "nested": [
          {
            "name": "b",
            "type": "text",
            "label": "b nested"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to [Petr Malimánek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64226652/14017240), if you don't know ahead of time which parameters will need to be removed, you can pass their names as an input parameter, like so:

```
function omit(collection, ...fields) {
    const result = {};
        
    for (let key in collection) {
        if (!fields.includes(key)) {
            result[key] = collection[key];
        }
    }
        
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to omit the name or exclude the input parameter at this time. We're planning to add a new flag that allows you to exclude specific fields like this one but now you have to filter out this parameter in the communication of the module.

You can use a custom Javascript function where you can remove all redundant parameters.

E.g.

**Communication:**

```json
{
   "body": "{{prepareBody(body)}}"
}
```